# populating nested dictionaries with rows from Pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, dictionary, indexing

I'm trying to populate a dictionary of dictionaries with entries from a Pandas data frame in Python by iterating through the nested dictionary and populating the values of each sub-dictionary with entries from a row of a Pandas data frame.

Although there are as many sub-dictionaries as there are rows in the data frame, all dictionaries get populated with the data from the last row of the data frame, instead of using every row for every dictionary.

Here is a toy reproducible example.

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize an empty df
data = pd.DataFrame()

# populate data frame with entries
data['name'] = ['Joe Smith', 'Mary James', 'Charles Williams']
data['school'] =  ["Jollywood Secondary", "Northgate Sixth From", "Brompton High"]
data['subjects'] = [['Maths', 'Art', 'Biology'], ['English', 'French', 'History'], ['Chemistry', 'Biology', 'English']]

# use dictionary comprehensions to set up main dictionary and sub-dictionary templates

# sub-dictionary
keys = ['name', 'school', 'subjects']
record = {key: None for key in keys}

# main dictionary
keys2 = ['cand1', 'cand2', 'cand3']
candidates = {key: record for key in keys2}

# as a result i get something like this
# {'cand1': {'name': None, 'school': None, 'subjects': None},
# 'cand2': {'name': None, 'school': None, 'subjects': None},
# 'cand3': {'name': None, 'school': None, 'subjects': None}}

# iterate through main dictionary and populate each sub-dict with row of df
for i, d in enumerate(candidates.items()):

    d[1]['name'] = data['name'].iloc[i]
    d[1]['school'] = data['school'].iloc[i]
    d[1]['subjcts'] = data['subjects'].iloc[i]

# what i end up with is the last row entry in each sub-dictionary
#{'cand1': {'name': 'Charles Williams',
#  'school': 'Brompton High',
#  'subjects': None,
#  'subjcts': ['Chemistry', 'Biology', 'English']},
# 'cand2': {'name': 'Charles Williams',
#  'school': 'Brompton High',
#  'subjects': None,
#  'subjcts': ['Chemistry', 'Biology', 'English']},
# 'cand3': {'name': 'Charles Williams',
#  'school': 'Brompton High',
#  'subjects': None,
#  'subjcts': ['Chemistry', 'Biology', 'English']}}
```

How do I need to modify my code to get each dictionary populated with a different row from my data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not work through your code to look for the bug, because the solution is a one-liner with the method `to_dict`.

Here is a minimal working example with your sample data.

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize an empty df
data = pd.DataFrame()

# populate data frame with entries
data['name'] = ['Joe Smith', 'Mary James', 'Charles Williams']
data['school'] =  ["Jollywood Secondary", "Northgate Sixth From", "Brompton High"]
data['subjects'] = [['Maths', 'Art', 'Biology'], ['English', 'French', 'History'], ['Chemistry', 'Biology', 'English']]

# redefine index to match your keys
data.index = ['cand{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,len(data)+1)]

# convert to dict
data_dict = data.to_dict(orient='index')

print(data_dict)
```

This will look something like this

```
{'cand1': {
     'name': 'Joe Smith', 
     'school': 'Jollywood Secondary', 
     'subjects': ['Maths', 'Art', 'Biology']},
 'cand2': {
     'name': 'Mary James', 
     'school': 'Northgate Sixth From', 
     'subjects': ['English', 'French', 'History']},
 'cand3': {
     'name': 'Charles Williams', 
     'school': 'Brompton High', 
     'subjects': ['Chemistry', 'Biology', 'English']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider avoiding the roundabout away of building dictionary as Pandas maintains various methods to render nested structures such as [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html). Specifically, consider adding a new column, *cand* and set it as index for `to_dict` output:

```
data['cand'] = 'cand' + pd.Series((data.index.astype('int') + 1).astype('str'))

mydict = data.set_index('cand').to_dict(orient='index')

print(mydict)

{'cand1': {'name': 'Joe Smith', 'school': 'Jollywood Secondary', 
           'subjects': ['Maths', 'Art', 'Biology']}, 
 'cand2': {'name': 'Mary James', 'school': 'Northgate Sixth From', 
           'subjects': ['English', 'French', 'History']}, 
 'cand3': {'name': 'Charles Williams', 'school': 'Brompton High', 
           'subjects': ['Chemistry', 'Biology', 'English']}}
```